# Spark Scala creating schema based on target JSON structure

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm hopelessly stuck trying to generate my Spark Schema based on the JSON structure I know I want.
I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4",
  "key5": [
    "key6": "value6",
    "key7": [
      "key8": "value8",
      "key8": "value9"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried to recreate the structure by creating the following Schema in Spark 2.4.8, running in Scala:

```
val targetSchemaSO = StructType(
    List(
    StructField("key1", StringType, true),
    StructField("key2", StringType, true),
    StructField("key3", StringType, true),
    StructField("key4", StringType, true),
    StructField("key5", StructType(
        List(
        StructField("key6", StringType, true),
        StructField("key7", ArrayType(StructType(
            List(
            StructField("key8", StringType, true)
            ))), true)
        )), true)
    )
)
```

However, when trying to format each row as a Spark Row using this code:

```
val outputDictSO = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, Any](
    "key1" -> "value1",
    "key2" -> "value2",
    "key3" -> "value3",
    "key4" -> "value4",
    "key5" -> (
        "key6" -> "value6",
        "key7" -> (
            "key8" -> "value8",
            "key8" -> "value9"
        )  
    )
)
return Row.fromSeq(output_dict.values.toSeq)
```

I get the following error when mapping it to the provided Schema:

```
Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2 is not a valid external
type for schema of struct<key6:string,key7:array<struct<key8:string>>>
```

The program I'm basing this off of uses this exact Schema in PySpark and the DataFrame is created just fine; do the StructTypes work differently between PySpark and Spark Scala? What would be the correct Schema to make so that nested arrays in the Schema are possible?

Comment: But your json structure is wrong or ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use from_json function ,pass the json string column as input and printSchema to retrieve valid schema. (Use one set of json string from the data and create dataframe if needed)

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("json",from_json(json_string_column))
    df1.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in creating the DataFrame schema in both languages. If you want to create a dataframe with a specified schema, the correct way to build the Rows, according to that provided schema, could be something like:

```
val outputDictSO =
  Row("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4",
    Row("value6", Array(
      Row("value8"))))

val df0 = 
  spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(outputDictSO)), targetSchemaSO)

df0.printSchema()
```

The dataframe´s schema is as expected:

```
root
 |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key5: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key6: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key7: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key8: string (nullable = true)
```

If you see the content of the dataframe:

```
df0.show()
```

Gives:

```
+------+------+------+------+--------------------+
|  key1|  key2|  key3|  key4|                key5|
+------+------+------+------+--------------------+
|value1|value2|value3|value4|[value6, [[value8]]]|
+------+------+------+------+--------------------+
```

You can select for a nested key:

```
df0.select("key5.key6").show()
```

Spark returns:

```
+------+
|  key6|
+------+
|value6|
+------+
```

The error is because the specified schema and the data do not match. If you take your data:

```
val outputDictSOMap = Map(
  "key1" -> "value1",
  "key2" -> "value2",
  "key3" -> "value3",
  "key4" -> "value4",
  "key5" -> (
    "key6" -> "value6",
    "key7" -> (
      "key8" -> "value8",
      "key9" -> "value9"
    )
  ))
```

And convert it to json:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

val json = Serialization.write(outputDictSOMap)
val df1 = spark.read.json(Seq(json).toDS)
df1.printSchema()
```

The resulting schema is:

```
root
 |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key5: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key6: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key7: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key8: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key9: string (nullable = true)
```

And that is the reason of your error.